# Two beginner questions about align correctly

Tags: modeling

## Aligment 1

So, I need this guy (left)

[image: Img1]

be perfectly alligned with this another one (right) by its angle on top, like this

[image: Img2]

That align isn't perfect as you see

## Aligment 2

I need this other guy

[image: Img3]

Be perfectly parallel to the angle on the other object

[image: Img4]

Like this

[image: Img5]

I'll appreciate any kind of advices and methods, Thanks!

Comment: I have a possible solution for both, but first I need to know if you have any other restrictions to this? Like, say prespecified measurements?

Comment: Or the distance between the two blocks or something like that

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming there are no predetermined measurements**

**Alignment I**

- In an empty scene create a cube and scale it down on the X and Y axis only to about half the original, by press Shift + Z.

[image]

- Then in edit mode, switch to Right view by pressing Num3, select both the top and bottom edges and scale down on the Z axis by about 0.5.

[image]

- Add three vertical loop cuts and adjust the other two closer to the middle one by select one of edge, then tapping G twice to enter Edge Slide Mode and sliding it closer to the middle loop.

[image]

[image]

- Delete the faces around the middle loop. Then select the edges around the open part and create a face by pressing F for both the segments.

[image]

[image]

**Alignment II**

- While still in edit mode, enter Face Select Mode and select the top face of the larger segment and press Shift + S and select cursor to selected to align the cursor to the point.

[image]

- Then create a cube and scale it down to the desired size. Select only the newly created cube completely and rotate it around the X axis, while using the "face dots" to check your alignment. press P and select "By loose Parts".

[image]

- Select that cube, and in edit mode, select Normal Orientation and select the top face and pull it using the manipulator along its normal Z axis. Repeat the same step for the bottom face till it is at the distance you want it to be from the other surface.

[image]

**NOTE:** If there are any predetermined measurements feel free to alter the scaling transformations as you see fit.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Alignment 2

Not sure if this is the best solution but in your case you could use the boolean-modifier.

1. add bolean-modifier to the upper object
2. set lower object as target and put operation on *Difference*
3. move the upper object down into the other
4. apply the modifier and move your upper object back to its position

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not what I wanted but thanks for the method, i'll use it

Answer (score 1):

I have a possible solution for #2:

- Select the big object and go into Edit mode.
- Select the face you want to align your object to.
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num1</kbd> to align your view to the face. (If you don't have a number pad, you can turn on Emulate Numpad in the preferences. Be sure to hit the Save User Settings button, or you'll lose the preferences changes when you quit!)
- Go out of Edit mode and select the other object.
- Hit <kbd>Num5</kbd> to go into "orthographic" mode, where there is no perspective. (Far away objects look just as big as close by objects.)
- Apply the object's scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Otherwise it'll get reset when you do the next step.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num0</kbd> to make Blender pretend the object is a camera.
- Press <kbd>Num0</kbd> to exit this "camera".
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num0</kbd> to align the "camera" to the view.
- Press <kbd>Num0</kbd> to exit the "camera" again.
- Press <kbd>Num5</kbd> to exit orthographic mode.

At this point, the rotation will be correct, but you will have to move it to where you want it to be. You'll also have to make Blender use the actual camera again (just select it and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num0</kbd>).

Comment: It worked! however I would like to know some fastest method, but thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Yes, my method is a bit of a kludge. (: